# How to parse a CSV file with different line elements without using an external library?

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to parse a CSV file in Python; the elements in the file increase after the first line from 6 to 7.

CSV example:

```
Title,Name,Job,Email,Address,ID
Eng.,"FirstName, LastName",Engineer,email@company.com,ACME Company,1234567
Eng.,"FirstName, LastName",Engineer,email@company.com,ACME Company,1234567
```

I need a way to format and present the output into a clean table.

From my understanding, the problem with my code is that starting from the second line, the CSV elements increase from 6 to 7. Thus, it throws the following error.

```
print(stringFormat.format(item.split(',')[0], item.split(',')[1], item.split(',')[2],
                          item.split(',')[3], item.split(',')[4], item.split(',')[5],))
IndexError: list index out of range
```

My code:

```
stringFormat = "{:>10} {:>10} {:>10} {:>10} {:>10}  {:>10}"

with open("the_file", 'r') as file:
     for item in file.readlines():
            print(stringFormat.format(item.split(',')[0], item.split(',')[1],
                                      item.split(',')[2], item.split(',')[3],
                                      item.split(',')[4], item.split(',')[5],
                                      item.split(',')[6]))
```

Comment: When you see quotes in a csv file, that indicates that everything enclosed in the quotes is a _single field_, even though it may contain a comma within the quotes. So your lines only have 6 columns, just like your header. The `csv` library is a part of the standard library of python (it's not an external library). Use that, it handles the correct parsing of csv files including quotes. If you aren't allowed to even use that, then you're going to have to think about how to avoid splitting the line on a comma that is enclosed in quotes.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi, thank you for the reply, but I don't want to use any library. My code works, except after the first line, I get the error because of the increased element (ID). Try the code. And you'll see what I mean.

Comment: @Al1nuX: Just because there was no error does not mean your code worked correctly.

Comment: If anyone kindly tries to run the code, will understand what is the issue. The code can only work with a fixed number of index. Once the index increases, it will throw the error. I need a solution that can adjust with the change of index.

Comment: I wonder who downvoted? at least try to contribute or stop downvoting other people's questions. What is not so clear, unuseful or no effort about the question?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but think the reason someone did was because your understanding of the problem was wrong (or the completely artificial constraint of not using external libraries).

Comment: @martineau, and that's why I'm asking for help in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with very simple for loops as shown below. I've added a print statement to show the effects

```py
# 'r' is not needed, it is the default value if omitted
with open("file_name") as infile:
    result = []
    # split the read() into a list of lines
    # I prefer this over readlines() as this removes the EOL character
    # automagically (I mean the `\n` char) 
    for line in infile.read().splitlines():
        # check if line is empty (stripping all spaces)
        if len(line.strip()) == 0: 
            continue
        # another way would be to check for ',' characters
        if ',' not in line:
            continue
        # set some helper variables
        line_result = []
        found_quote = False
        element = ""
        # iterate over the line by character
        for c in line:
            # toggle the found_quote if quote found
            if c == '"':
                found_quote = not found_quote
                continue
            if c == ",":
                if found_quote:
                    element += c
                else:
                    # append the element to the line_result and reset element
                    line_result.append(element)
                    element = ""
            else:
                # append c to the element
                element += c
        # append leftover element to the line_result
        line_result.append(element)
        
        # append the line_result to the final result
        result.append(line_result)
        print(len(line_result), line_result)


print('------------------------------------------------------------')
stringFormat = "{:>10} {:>20} {:>20} {:>20} {:>20}  {:>10}"

for line in result:
    print(stringFormat.format(*line))
```

output

```py
6 ['Title', 'Name', 'Job', 'Email', 'Address', 'ID']
6 ['Eng.', 'FirstName, LastName', 'Engineer', 'email@company.com', 'ACME Company', '1234567']
6 ['Eng.', 'FirstName, LastName', 'Engineer', 'email@company.com', 'ACME Company', '1234567']
------------------------------------------------------------
     Title                 Name                  Job                Email              Address          ID
      Eng.  FirstName, LastName             Engineer    email@company.com         ACME Company     1234567
      Eng.  FirstName, LastName             Engineer    email@company.com         ACME Company     1234567
```

### Some adjustments after talking.

Notes about sorting a list of lists. It will compare the first element of the inner lists to eachother. If they match, it will compare the second element of the inner lists to eachother, etc. Because of this, you might want to move the ID column to the second column in the resulting list, as this seems to be what is called a unique identifier (UID).

```py
with open("file_name") as infile:
    lines = infile.read().splitlines()

# set the header and remove it from lines.
header = lines.pop(0).split(',')
# rearrange the header to put the last element (date) first
# -1 gets the last element (eg, count from end)
header.insert(0, header.pop(-1))

# store the header length as this will speed up the process for longer files
# otherwise you would have to call len(header) in each iteration of the loop
header_len = len(header)

result = []
for line in lines:
    if ',' not in line:
        continue
    # split the line once here, so we don't have to split it a million
    # times in the rest of the loop
    split_line = line.split(',')
    if len(split_line) > header_len:
        # note, you can remove the strip('"') if you want to keep the quotation marks
        # also note that .pop() removes the element "in place", which is why I
        # use .pop(1) twice. first time it gets firstname, second time it gets lastname
        split_line.insert(1, f"{split_line.pop(1)},{split_line.pop(1)}".strip('"'))
    # move the date element to the start
    split_line.insert(0, split_line.pop(-1))
    # do some slicing on the date element to turn it into YYYYMMDD as this allows for
    # proper sorting without any hassle. I'm assuming the date you provided is in the format
    # MM/DD/YYYY. You can easily move the order around if it's DD/MM/YYYY
    # Also, pad day/month with leading zero's using f"{string:>02}"
    split_line[0] = f"{split_line[0].split('/')[2]}{split_line[0].split('/')[0]:>02}{split_line[0].split('/')[1]:>02}"
    result.append(split_line)

# sort it. Since the date is in numeric format, and the first element, it sorts 
# properly automagically
result.sort()

# if you want you can re-format the date again. you can do so with some list slicing
# since the date string is now properly formatted this is very easy to do
# because the sort() above happens outside the initial loop, we cannot do it inside said loop
for line in result:
    line[0] = f"{line[0][6:]}/{line[0][4:6]}/{line[0][0:4]}"

# insert the header
result.insert(0, header)


stringFormat = "{:>10} {:>25} {:>20} {:>20} {:>20} {:>10} {:>10}"
for line in result:
    print(stringFormat.format(*line))


# write it as a CSV file with ; used as separator instead
with open("output.csv", "w") as outfile:
    for line in result:
        outfile.write(";".join(line) + "\n")
```

---

Comment: Excellent solution also. really helpful, Can you edit the code to include ( with open("file_name", 'r') as file: ) statement please?

Comment: done, note that the `'r'` is not needed when opening files to read...

Comment: I would vote 2 times if I can! thank you brother, this will help me learn more about reading and manipulating files. However, I'm getting the error at the end:     print(stringFormat.format(*line))
IndexError: Replacement index 1 out of range for positional args tuple

Comment: I think you might have empty lines in your input file, I added two examples of sanity checks directly below the first for loop. Also note that you can accept the answer instead of upvoting :-)

Comment: If the last column on the right is a date table, is it possible to bring it to the left and make it the first table, sort out the dates in order from top to down? and write to a file?

Comment: Yes to all of that. *List slicing* is your friend there for the reordering, and for the date. For the sorting, this depends a bit on how the date is actually formatted. You can always just import datetime and convert it to a datetime object which allows for easier handling. Can you provide a sample of the actual string for the date?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243051/discussion-between-al1nux-and-edo-akse).

Comment: I get this error 'print(stringFormat.format(*line))
IndexError: Replacement index 6 out of range for positional args tuple'

Comment: did you change the stringFormat? I added one element as the date column got added. If not, try printing out the line for debugging to see if the line that throws the error actually matches what you expect.

Comment: I have removed one of the "{:>10}" it works now.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this. The for loop uses the length of the splitted item, so you can have lines that are variable in length.

```py
stringFormats = ["{:>10}", "{:>10}", "{:>10}", "{:>10}", "{:>10}", "{:>10}", "{:>10}"]

with open("the_file", 'r') as file:
    for item in file.readlines():
        s_item = item.split(',')
        f_item = ''
        for x in range(len(s_item)):
            f_item += stringFormats[x].format(s_item[x])
        print(f_item)
```

Of course, you need at least enough stringFormats to match the greatest line length. If you never need to use a different option, then you could just change stringFormat back to a single string instead of looping through it.

```py
stringFormat = "{:>10}"

with open("the_file", 'r') as file:
    for item in file.readlines():
        s_item = item.split(',')
        f_item = ''
        for a_field in s_item:
            f_item += stringFormat.format(a_field)
        print(f_item)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Your code works! However, I don't understand what s_item and f_item stand for. Also, the items displayed have no lines between them; how can I specify and adjust the spaces between them? And one last thing, how can I remove the " " from "FirstName, LastName" in the output?